# Historical basis and mathematical significance of Riemann surfaces

Tags: riemann-surfaces, soft-question, ho.history-overview

It is written in *[Riemann Surfaces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199606749)* (Oxford Graduate Texts in Mathematics) by Simon Donaldson, that:

"[t]he theory of Riemann surfaces occupies a very special place in mathematics. It is a culmination of much of traditional calculus"

Can someone please provide an articulated commentary on this statement.

Specifically, the statement suggests, [or seems to suggest], that Riemann surfaces were the logical / mathematical outcome of many years of careful development and refinement of traditional calculus. But: (i) what was / were the major milestones(s) in this road? and (ii) when the author uses the word 'culmination' what specifically is it the culmination of, and what problems / issues did the introduction of Riemann surfaces help to solve / clarify / etc.?

---

(This question was originally [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64727/historical-basis-and-mathematical-significance-of-riemann-surfaces) on Math SE, but I'm also posting it here because I'm seeking an expert's [in Riemann surface theory] feedback if possible.)

Comment: Why do you ask? 

Comment: If you consider traditional calculus to mean calculus in one variable, then that leads to complex analysis in one variable. At first it was done on C, but for more flexibility (particularly in relation to speaking about analytic continuation without awkward branch cuts) Riemann introduced the idea of doing complex analysis on a one-dimensional complex manifold, and those are essentially the same thing as Riemann surfaces.

Comment: Not research-level, so wrong site to ask your questions. Why would you think that an expert in Riemann surfaces today would necessarily be the right person to ask about historical development of the subject?

Comment: Vote to close. And -1, for **again** crossposting; three hours is a ridiculously short time to wait.

Comment: @Ahmed, thank you for letting me know about Donaldson´s book.

Comment: @Sadiq : mathematics-education is used for questions about teaching, not learning.  I think the FAQ makes it clear that MO is intended for professional mathematicians.  Also, the MO users who are interested in answering questions from undergraduates already read math.SE..  Finally, while it is true that questions about mathematical history are welcome here, your question is not really a serious math-history question.  If you already knew about Riemann surfaces and complex analysis, the answer would be pretty clear.

Comment: I'm not going to express an opinion about whether or not the question should be closed, but I want to give my interpretation of why others object.  First, the mathematics-education tag is not appropriate for your question; it is meant for questions about mathematical pedagogy.  (Actually, most questions with this tag would not be considered research level within the math education community, but I don't think there are enough experts in the field who frequent this site for the tag to be enforced.)  Your question is about Riemann surfaces, not about education.

Comment: First and foremost and again, do not crosspost! If you prefer to ask here, do/try so. The mathematics-education tag is for questions *on* mathematics education; check what is tagged with this. Precisely from math for math asking how to educate/teach something/body. However, the faqs tell pretty preciselly what the site is about: "MathOverflow's primary goal is for users to ask and answer research level math questions..."
Also you seem to know from your first question that MO is for graduate level and higher and support such an idea. I could go on, but lets leave it at that. 

Comment: Second, there is a well-known narrative which explains the passage from single variable calculus over $\mathbb{C}$ to the theory of Riemann surfaces.  It is often described in basic complex analysis / algebraic geometry courses.  So while your question is consistent with the history-overview tag, it isn't really "research level" as is.  A good question of this sort would identify a substantive mathematical issue which is implicit in the narrative; see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/41253/who-fixed-the-topology-on-ideles/41332#41332 for an example.

Comment: @Andy: @quid: Ok. Thanks for the responses. - Sadiq @Paul: ok. This is very useful. Thank you. - Sadiq

Comment: Andy, I'm not so sure that the historical development would be so 'clear' to just anybody who had had exposure to Riemann surfaces, complex analysis, and so on. It's not super-clear to me, at any rate -- but my guess is that the advent of Riemann surfaces was, for Riemann, firmly grounded in things like elliptic function theory and abelian integrals. As I say, this is a *guess*. I'll bet someone at MO would be able to offer something more authoritative, and there could be someone here who has made a serious study of the history. I honestly don't find the question all that objectionable. 

Comment: (What I should have said is that the question taken in isolation is not all that objectionable -- although it obviously be a lot better. However, I fully agree that cross-posting is objectionable.) 

Comment: **Meta** http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1137/historical-basis-rieman-surfaces/ And in brief: Todd, yes the crosspost is which is seriously dislike; for context please see meta (in a couple minutes).

Comment: @Sadiq: your question received much more detailed answers on SE than on MO, and the answers arrived **earlier**. If this is not conclusive proof that your question was more at home on SE, I don't know what is.

Comment: @Paul: "... there is a well-known narrative which explains the passage from single variable calculus over C to the theory of Riemann surfaces. It is often described in basic complex analysis / algebraic geometry courses."  -- Some references? - Regards

Answer (score 6):

From the wording of your question it is possible you are asking someone to write an entire historical overview for you. So instead what I did was spend a few minutes on Ye Olde Google and found this:

[The Concept of a Riemann Surface](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486470040.html) by Hermann Weyl. It is cheap and your local library might have it already it.

Comment: This is more of a technical book. I was searching for an outline-type response.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for an outline, check Chapter III of 
"The Riemann legacy: Riemannian ideas in mathematics and physics"
 By Krzysztof Maurin

Here is the link to Google Books, where you can view the table of content

http://books.google.com/books?id=jlll448aDLEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=inauthor:Maurin&hl=en&ei=5CpyTr2-HOGusQLfz-X1CQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false